# While runnig Tkinter application it shows the name of application as Tk on taskbar, I have to change that name. How can I change that name?

Tags: python, tkinter

[A Tkinter application, want to change name shown on taskbar while running application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8ZYH.png)

Comment: try this, `root = Tk()` and `root.title('whatevername')`

Comment: `title` function does not help on Ubuntu 22.04.3 with GNOME for the top-left program title as [the OP has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63298521) and in [the taskbar](https://i.imgur.com/BNwuuEG.png).